# Consuming an REST API with Node.JS for a AWS Lambda Function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I just starting to learn how to develop Amazon Alexa Skills using the Alexa Skills Kit and AWS Lambda. I don't quite understand how to call an API and retrieve data from it. I found this template code from a Jordan Leigh video:

```
var endpoint = ""; // ENDPOINT GOES HERE
var body = "";
https.get(endpoint, (response) => {
  response.on('data', (chunk) => body += chunk);
  response.on('end', () => {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    var subscriberCount = data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount;
    context.succeed(
      generateResponse(
        buildSpeechletResponse(`Current subscriber count is ${subscriberCount}`, true),
        {}
      )
    );
  });
});
```

I understand that the `endpoint` variable will hold the url for the API, but I am unsure about the rest. In this code I believe he using a YouTube API for the current subscriber count. If I wanted to, for example, use the Dark Sky API to extract weather info, how would I go about this using this similar format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much the same.

```
const https = require('https');
var body = "";

const url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/your-secret-key/37.8267,-122.4233"


var req = https.request(url, (res) => {

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    body += d;
  });

  res.on('end', () => {
       var data = JSON.parse(body);
       console.log("daily weather: ", data.daily);
  });


});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});

req.end();
```

Comment: When I enter this into the service simulator, it says "the response is invalid"

Comment: The above code was in response to your request of an example using Dark Sky API. You must have your own key and substitute the in the url. If you test using `node yourFileName.js` you will see it works.